# Android Revert seekbar back to original Position(Right To Left)

Tags: android

I am trying to implement Locker App and swipe unlock functionality using android seekbar.

What I want is, swipe to unlock from right to left and if user release touch from drawable then it should come back to right side of the layout.

Using following code, I am able to achieve the same but for Left to Right direction, I want to do the same in opposite direction i.e Right to Left.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

public class SlideButton extends SeekBar {

private Drawable thumb;
private SlideButtonListener listener;

public SlideButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public void setThumb(Drawable thumb) {
    super.setThumb(thumb);
    this.thumb = thumb;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        if (thumb.getBounds().contains((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY())) {
            super.onTouchEvent(event);
        } else
            return false;
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        if (getProgress() > 70)
            handleSlide();

        setProgress(0);
    } else
        super.onTouchEvent(event);

    return true;
}

private void handleSlide() {
    listener.handleSlide();
}

public void setSlideButtonListener(SlideButtonListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}   
}

interface SlideButtonListener {
public void handleSlide();
}
```

NOTE: In above code when user click on drawable to swipe from left to right, and if he releases his finger from drawable, with seekbar Progress < 70, then the icon/drawable comes back to original position i.e to left corner.

So, my question is simple how could I achieve same functionality using above code to swipe unlock from right to left.

I have tried to achieve this using following code, it do shows me drawable icon to right side but when i try to swipe it from right to left it doesn't functions as expected.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

public class ReversedSeekBar extends SeekBar {

private Drawable thumb;
private SlideButtonListener listener;

public ReversedSeekBar(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ReversedSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}


public ReversedSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
public void setThumb(Drawable thumb) {
    super.setThumb(thumb);
    this.thumb = thumb;
}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    float px = this.getWidth() / 2.0f;
    float py = this.getHeight() / 2.0f;

    canvas.scale(-1, 1, px, py);
    //canvas.rotate(180, px, py);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        if (thumb.getBounds().contains((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY())) {
            super.onTouchEvent(event);
        } else
            return false;

    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        if (getProgress() > 70)
            handleSlide();
        setProgress(0);

    } else
        super.onTouchEvent(event);

    return true;
}

private void handleSlide() {
    listener.handleSlide();
}

public void setSlideButtonListener(SlideButtonListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

}
```

Thanks...

Comment: How about flip/rotate the slide view?

Comment: I tried rotating the seekbar, but not working.

Comment: I wonder why it's not working, because it's the same as left-to-right, but you rotate it 180 degrees so it's right-to-left, isn't it?

Comment: If you see the second example i tried rotating the canvas, but it wont detect touch event from right to left, the touch event still the same from left to right.

Answer (score 6):

Try adding these two lines to xml. (It did the trick for me)

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
android:mirrorForRtl="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

**In Kotlin:**

Check the default language code containing "ar"

```
 when {
      Locale.getDefault().language == "ar" -> {             
          clSeekbar.scaleX = -1                
      }
```

Comment: this is not enough since Arabic is not the only RTL Language !